# R Combining and creating functions

Tags: r, function

Here's my code

```
mean <- 100
sd <- 15
Fluorescence_Intensity = rnorm(x, mean, sd)
```

I would like to create a function that calculates Fluorescence Intensity for me where I can give and change the value of sd mean and distribution for example rnorm to dnorm.
As I am new to both R as in this forum, please help

Comment: S_R, yesterday I wanted to answer your question on how to create a function so you can output effect from a dose. But it seems that you deleted it. If you put your question back, I can answer to it, I have the code on my computer

Comment: Sorry for that I don't know how I am really new on this form and this delete was by accident.

Comment: Concerning this topic, I don't get what you want to do since it seems that you put the exact same arguments in `Fluorescence_Intensity` as in `rnorm` function so I don't know why you would create a new function. Also I could not find function doorm.

Comment: Sorry it dnorm I want to be one function want my function when I can change sd, mean and rnorm for dnorm named Fluorescence_Intensity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit: I added the qnorm function**

This should do the job:

```
Fluorescence_Intensity <- function(X, MEAN, SD, METHOD, LOWER.TAIL=TRUE, LOG.P=FALSE){
  if(METHOD=="rnorm"){
    res <- rnorm(X, MEAN, SD)
    }
  if(METHOD=="dnorm"){
    res <- dnorm(X, MEAN, SD)
    }
  if(METHOD=="qnorm"){
    res <- qnorm(X, MEAN, SD, LOWER.TAIL, LOG.P)
    }
  print(res)
}

Fluorescence_Intensity(X=10, MEAN=100, SD=7, METHOD="rnorm")
Fluorescence_Intensity(X=10, MEAN=100, SD=7, METHOD="dnorm")
Fluorescence_Intensity(X=0.8, MEAN=100, SD=7, METHOD="qnorm")
Fluorescence_Intensity(X=0.8, MEAN=100, SD=7, METHOD="qnorm", LOWER.TAIL=FALSE, LOG.P=FALSE)
```

Comment: Tanks that answer my question

Comment: and if I want add qnorm it is good way? if(METHOD=="qnorm"){ res <- dnorm(X, MEAN, SD, LOWER.TAIL, LOG.P) }

Comment: You only missed the right function as follows: `if(METHOD=="qnorm"){ res <- qnorm(X, MEAN, SD, LOWER.TAIL, LOG.P) }`. But you have to add `LOWER.TAIL=NULL, LOG.P=NULL` in the arguments of your function when you create it so that it only takes into account these arguments if you fill/use it when you use the function as in the very last part of the code. Thus the arguments of the header would be : `function(X, MEAN, SD, METHOD, LOWER.TAIL=NULL, LOG.P=NULL){`

Comment: Updated the code with 2 more examples